# Posting images from camera roll to facebook in xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, facebook, xcode4.5

I've got some functionality set up.  But I'm lost on where to go from here.  I can probably figure out what to do with facebook once I know how to actually use the images.  I tried saving the image into NSDictionary and then redirecting to a different View Controller, but it won't let me redirect from within the imagePickerController method.  So anybody have any idea how to use the image selected from camera roll?

My next idea was to save it in the NSDictionary and then just have a statement checking to see if the NSdictionary value changed but that's not an efficient way of doing it at all.

EDITED below to include the answer provided, but nothing happens, no image displays or anything.  What am I missing?

```
- (void) useCameraRoll
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                              nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
    newMedia = NO;
}
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType = [info
                       objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = [info
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    NSLog(@"image:%@",image);


    displayPhoto.image = image;
    [displayPhoto setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [[self view] addSubview:displayPhoto];

}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have called this from a view controller with a button that you have created, why not just add a UIImageView onto your view controller? Call it myPhotoImageView or something like that and then in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, just add the following line of code after

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

as

```
myPhotoImageView.image = image;
```

To size the image view so that the aspect looks nice do this.

```
CGSize size = image.size;
CGRect photoFrame;
if (size.width > size.height)
{
    // Landscape
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 320 / size.width;
    photoFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, size.height*scaleFactor);
}
else
{
    // Portrait
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 320 / size.height;
    photoFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width*scaleFactor, 320);
}
myPhotoImageView.frame = photoFrame;
```

Comment: I had to change it to use to a UIImageView in IB... that made it work.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Glad you are on the right track now :-)

Comment: I have an issue with landscape images displaying properly.  They smush the landscape image into portrait height/width and looks pretty fugly :/.  Any ideas?

Comment: In interface builder change your UIImageView Mode to Aspect Fill or Aspect Fit depending on your preference. You can also get the image size as CGSize imageSize = image.size and resize your UIImageView frame accordingly (imageSize.width etc.), then, if you use Aspect Fill or Aspect Fit, the image will scale nicely for you.

Comment: That helps, but doesn't totally solve the problem.  Now, I either end up with the sides being cut out completely, or black spaces on the top and bottom, and if you rotate nothing happens.  Rotating can't be used either, since I had to disable rotating permanently within the app because AVCam from app wouldn't support landscape.

Comment: OK I added how to resolve this in my answer - the example assumes a 320 point width. You can change this to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: hmm :/ still not what I need.  Aspect fill is good for portrait images, but landscape images lose the sides.  With this method, it shrinks everything and leaves a bunch of black space.  If we have to do this for landscape it's better than nothing, just leave black space behind, but it looks pretty bad using this method for portrait.  Is there a way to distinguish if an image is portrait or not?

Comment: That's what I put in the code. Use it all the time and works nicely.

Comment: Ok I see, yea so I just did nothing for potrait, and then your code for landscape, and we're like 90% of the way there :p.  Not totally happy with the landscape image only fitting on top, but it's probably good enough to go live with if I can't figure out how to rotate the image manually.  Thanks for your help